# booting windows 7 / linux mint 19.1, on HDD / external SSD

Tags: windows-7, ssd, multi-boot, linux-mint

I am a beginner.

I need to know how to make a dual booting for Windows 7 and Linux mint, with internal HDD and external SSD?

I would like to use a new SSD, with caddy DVD/ SSD, in order to boot Linux Mint from it.

How to make partition on SSD -on caddy- ?

Then, how to create a bootable SSD ISO Partition on it for Linux mint for Windows,  and how to apply it?

Comment: What's "Caddy DVD/SSD"?

Comment: Is Win 7 already installed?  When you say caddy DVD/SSD, is this something like a bay where you plug in either a DVD or SSD (but not both at the same time)?  What media would you use to boot the Mint session for installation (a flash drive)?  You're probably aware that support for Win 7 will end in half a year.  After that it will be risky to use it, particularly to go online.  Are you factoring in plans for dealing with that?  What parts of the process are you already familiar with?  How big is the SSD?  In general, the typical sequence would be to install Windows first (cont'd)

Comment: if it is not already installed.  Then boot a Mint live session.  In the live session, partition the SSD as desired (depending on size, you could have separate partitions for root, home, and swap, perhaps one for creating snapshots with Timeshift or a similar program).  If you want to share files between Windows and Mint, you might carve out a partition on one of the drives and format it with a filesystem both OSes handle well).  Then you'd install Mint from the live session.  Specify where to put things yourself rather than using the installer wizard to avoid surprises.  (cont'd)

Comment: Have it put GRUB on the SSD.  Set the computer's boot order to check the SSD first.  That's basically it.  If you are totally unfamiliar with all of this, there is a lot of detail you should know for each piece of the process, and personal decisions you will need to make.  Covering everything in detail would be beyond the intended scope of a question on a Q&A site.  You would want to do a lot of online reading, review tutorials, etc.  If you have specific questions about pieces of the process or choices, each might make a question of the intended scope.

Comment: Yes, I have already windows 7, which I am familiar with it.

Comment: And I want to try Linux before the end of windows 7. I am a beginner. All my experience is to use windows 7 as a user only. I mean by caddy that fram which can be used in the place of DVD driver, to attach a SSD in it.I have not bought SSD yet, I need first to know if it will help or not. I thought about SSD because I found many problems about partitioning the HDD to create a dual  boot from it. I thought that using SSD may decrease the risks! But I am not sure yet, so I am asking about it.

Comment: In fact, all what I have installed, is the iso file:- linuxmint-19.1-cinnamon-64bit, with its two confirming files! I installed them on my laptop (with windows 7), and then burned it on DVDs, and also on USB flashes. That is all! And I am looking now for more understanding about what the second step should be. Because I want to be sure that it will be done without any risk. I think that all the windows 7 users, think in the same way!

Comment: A drive in that caddy isn't "external". And for better performance you should consider installing the SSD instead of the HDD and move the HDD to the caddy (reason: DVD bays may have an older/slower SATA controller). Partitioning is the same regardless of the drive type.

Comment: Thank you about correcting the description of the SSD. In fact I want to say that it is external of the internal HDD. I though that it is, in its reality, a kind of external addings to the computer, similar to the USB, but in different way. ++ I need to shorten the work, if it is possible, by using the present HDD, with the suitable SSD for Linux mint. And may be adding or changing the processor, if it could help!

Comment: You know that millions of the users of Windows 7, want to change safely into linux, without making big changings to their computers. they, and I also, are looking for an easy way to change to linux, before windows 7 will be dead! All of these millions are looking for a help, to do it easily, without need to spend months or years in studying the very deep issues. We need help, simply quick help!, before the death of windows 7.

Comment: Are there differences between connecting the SSD through caddy DVD/ SSD, and connecting it completely external through USB adaptor? Many thanks in advance

Comment: The partitioning is not easy in windows 7 because of the immovable files. Windows 7 refuses to shrink the HDD because of these files, and it is risky to enforce windows to do that! ++ Because of these conditions, may be it is more safe to let the internal HDD as it is, and use an external SSD, through USB, or through caddy on the DVD drive.++ Could you please help us in doing it! Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @MakramZakiShenouda, just FYI, if you address comments to a specific user with @, like I did here, they will get an alert to the posting.  Otherwise, they will be unaware of it unless they stumble across it.  re: caddy vs. external - if you are talking about an internal drive bay, that is usually connected the same as an internal drive.  That connection will be fast enough to keep up with any type of drive (HDD or SSD).  An external bay sometimes connects with a similar type of interface, but is often a USB connection.  (cont'd)

Comment: If it is USB 3.0 (caddy plus computer port), that will keep up with any kind of drive.  But if it is an older computer that came with Win 7, it's likely to be USB 2.0.  That will roughly keep up with a slow HDD but will be a bottleneck for an SSD.  The SSD will work, but it will be a waste of money because it won't be able to work any faster than a slow HDD.  re: HDD with Windows - Windows probably doesn't use more than a small fraction of the space on the drive.  (cont'd)

Comment: The fixed files are anchored in the middle of the drive.  They can be moved with a few steps, but even if you don't, you can defragment the files and also the free space to move the Windows content behind that "barrier".  Then you can shrink the Windows partition to that fixed point, which will free up half the drive.  You only need about 30 GB for Ubuntu to have plenty of room, including a normal amount of space for personal files.  If you have big collections of images or media files, you would want more space for those.

Comment: BTW, there's a fundamental difference between Windows and Linux.  Windows is designed to support people who just want to use the computer to get their work done, without needing any real familiarity with how things work.  And you can pretty much do that if you stick with what Microsoft provides and don't tinker with things.  If you don't want to upgrade to Win 10 and can afford the price, Apple computers are even better at hiding the inner workings.  Linux is getting better for non-technical users, and Mint is probably the most user-friendly distro.  (cont'd)

Comment: If you stick with what Mint provides, the experience can be almost like Windows in terms of not needing to give much of your focus to the operating system.  But Linux is "your" OS; you own it and are responsible for it.  You can do whatever you want to customize or change it.  If you encounter a problem, of your own making or some bug, there are resources to help solve it, but primary responsibility for fixing a problem with your own OS lies with you.  It's like the difference between home ownership and renting.  (cont'd)

Comment: If you rent, you expect to live there problem free; maintenance is someone else's responsibility. A homeowner is responsible for all the required maintenance.  You can hire people to do everything, but a lot of it will be faster and cheaper if you learn to do it yourself.  You refer to "risks".  That's not an accurate term.  You're really referring to things happening that interfere with getting your work done and that you lack familiarity with how to fix it.  Anything can be fixed, one way or another.  (cont'd)

Comment: The more familiarity you develop, and the more you're willing to take personal responsibility for, the easier and faster it will be to handle problems.  With Linux, you will encounter more things requiring you to focus on the OS.  Even preparing to transition will require more focus on Windows than you may have done in the past.

Comment: Many thanks for the brief illustrations
1 -- I tried Windows 10, and it made me expensive problems in many apparatus, like the expensive HP printer. When asking for the help of the site of HP, I found no really solutions, furthermore I found too many people complaining of problems after upgrading into Windows 10. The site of HP created a sub-site for the problems after Windows 10! Huge number of complaned people without a real solution. At end, I threw that expensive printer, and the other damaged things. (to be continued)

Comment: ++ I downloaded it.
++ The stumbling stone was the immovable files, which prevent from getting suitable unallocated spaces for creating a new partition.  
++ The steps that Windows gives to solve manually The immovable files, are complicated for an ordinary computer user!
++ A big crowd of users are complaining from problems after using 3rd party programs!
++ So, one must look for another way!
++ May be it is an external HDD or SSD!
++ For old laptops, with USB 2, it will more and more slow!
++ The alternative, is to use caddy adaptor with SSD in DVD driver.
(to be continued)

Comment: ++ The alternative, is to use caddy adaptor with SSD in DVD driver.
+++++ From here, I believe that all the similar windows 7’ users have to start, soon or later!
++ Especially with old laptops with USB 2, and with normal knowledge of computers systems, even if those people are highly graduated in other branches of science! 
I believe that this collection of conditions, concern millions of users!
++ Many thanks for any help, any explanation and any push in the right direction

Comment: I am sorry, I was intending to say: the detailed reply, and not: "brief" of course!